# How can I make an application change the firebase account from the application in android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I can link a firebase account to an android studio, but I want to be able to change that firebase account from the application.
**How do I do that? **

Comment: `from the application` means from Android Studio? or you want to change the account from the android app?

Comment: do you mean to edit json file data from the App?

Comment: yes I want to edit json file from the app.  
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you already used firebase in your application. Now you want to change this account. **It's only possible to create a new firebase new user account.**
2. If you want to use the same account with multiple user access that times you give firebase access to the rest of the users. **This way you manage the firebase account with multiple user access.**

Comment: Now my application is connected to my firebase account and I want to change it so that I can connect to another firebase account.
   I want to make an application is People who use this application can connect to the self firebase account.                        

Is this possible?

Comment: That time you create this project with your new firebase account. otherwise not possible to implement your desire target.